# Trying to find the highest improvement in score for a given city

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I tried grouping it by city, date and score. Then sorting by city and score and finally applying linear regression to calculate the highest slopes.

Code below

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
result = data.groupby(['facility_city', 'score', 'activity_date'], as_index=False).sum()
result = result.sort_values(by=['facility_city', 'activity_date'], ascending=True)
print(result)
result = result.apply(lambda v: linregress(v['activity_date'], v['score'])[0])
print(result)
```

An example of the data is

```
"activity_date","employee_id","facility_address","facility_city","facility_id","facility_name","facility_state","facility_zip","grade","owner_id","owner_name","pe_description","program_element_pe","program_name","program_status","record_id","score","serial_number","service_code","service_description"
2017-05-09,"EE0000593","17660 CHATSWORTH ST","GRANADA HILLS","FA0175397","HOVIK'S FAMOUS MEAT & DELI","CA","91344","A","OW0181955","JOHN'S FAMOUS MEAT & DELI INC.","FOOD MKT RETAIL (25-1,999 SF) HIGH RISK",1612,"HOVIK'S FAMOUS MEAT & DELI","ACTIVE","PR0168541",98,"DAHDRUQZO",1,"ROUTINE INSPECTION"
2017-04-10,"EE0000126","3615 PACIFIC COAST HWY","TORRANCE","FA0242138","SHAKEY'S PIZZA","CA","90505","A","OW0237843","SCO, LLC","RESTAURANT (61-150) SEATS HIGH RISK",1638,"SHAKEY'S PIZZA","ACTIVE","PR0190290",94,"DAL3SBUE0",1,"ROUTINE INSPECTION"
2017-04-04,"EE0000593","17515 CHATSWORTH ST","GRANADA HILLS","FA0007801","BAITH AL HALAL","CA","91344","A","OW0031150","SABIR MOHAMMAD SHAHID","FOOD MKT RETAIL (25-1,999 SF) HIGH RISK",1612,"BAITH AL HALAL","INACTIVE","PR0036723",95,"DAL2PIKJU",1,"ROUTINE INSPECTION"
2017-08-15,"EE0000971","44455 VALLEY CENTRAL WAY","LANCASTER","FA0013858","FOOD 4 LESS #306","CA","93536","A","OW0012108","FOOD 4 LESS, INC.","RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS HIGH RISK",1632,"FOOD 4 LESS DELI/BAKERY#306","ACTIVE","PR0039905",98,"DA0ZMAJXZ",1,"ROUTINE INSPECTION"
2016-09-26,"EE0000145","11700 SOUTH ST","ARTESIA","FA0179671","PHO LITTLE SAIGON","CA","90701","A","OW0185167","PHO SOUTH ST INC","RESTAURANT (61-150) SEATS HIGH RISK",1638,"PHO LITTLE SAIGON","ACTIVE","PR0173311",96,"DA41DBXA2",1,"ROUTINE INSPECTION"
2016-05-11,"EE0000720","1309 S HOOVER ST","LOS ANGELES","FA0179745","HAPPY TACOS TO GO","CA","90006-4903","A","OW0185239","MAT L. MORA","RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS HIGH RISK",1632,"HAPPY TACOS TO GO","INACTIVE","PR0173403",96,"DAURQTTVR",1,"ROUTINE INSPECTION"
2017-02-28,"EE0000741","4959 PATATA ST","CUDAHY","FA0012590","EL POTRERO CLUB","CA","90201","B","OW0036634","TSAY, SHYR JIN","RESTAURANT (151 + ) SEATS HIGH RISK",1641,"EL POTRERO CLUB","ACTIVE","PR0041708",87,"DAUNXDSVP",1,"ROUTINE INSPECTION"
```

I am getting an error KeyError: 'activity_date' when I try to apply the linear regression. Any tips would be welcome

Comment: Do you want to calculate the slopes for each group? Of after getting the sum by group you wanna to apply the liner regression and get an unique slope?

Comment: Also, when asking a question, don't provide the example as an image, since it's not reproducible. Add the example data as code: `data.head().to_dict()`.

Comment: I want to calculate the linear regression of activity date vs score for a given city. After that, find the city with the highest slope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `groupby` again to use `apply` like you did. Also, linear regression does not work with date directly, you'll need to convert them to numerical first (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65375313/trying-to-find-the-highest-improvement-in-score-for-a-given-city?noredirect=1#comment115580329_65375313)).

Change your last result assignment to:

```py
result = (result.groupby('facility_city')
 .apply(lambda x: linregress(x.activity_date.map(dt.datetime.toordinal), x.score)[0])
)
```

Your full code should look like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from scipy.stats import linregress

# To make sure activity_date is a Timestamp:
data['activity_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data.activity_date)

# Sort cities and dates
result = data.sort_values(['facility_city', 'activity_date'])

# Calculate linear regressions and retrieve their slopes
result = (result.groupby('facility_city')
 .apply(lambda x: linregress(x.activity_date.map(dt.datetime.toordinal), x.score)[0])
)

# Show higheest slopes first
result.sort_values(ascending=False)
```